# Jquery/JavaScript: How to append the data by column dynamically to each row in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append the data to each row by column-wise using jquery. I couldn't able to achieve this. My aim is to get data on the table as in the below pic. My fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Uq5yC/130/). I would appreciate someone helping me solve this.

[image: pic]

Jquery:

```
 var el = $('#dbg');
 var row = el.find('tr');
 var column = row.find('td');

 var HtmlData =  LoadData();
 el.html(HtmlData);
 column.html(HtmlData);
 row.append(column);
 el.append(row);


  function LoadData()
     {
     var dmJSON="http://api.railwayapi.com/route/train/12728/apikey/3dacdecg/";
     var html = '<div class="row s12"/>';
        $.ajax({
          url: dmJSON,
          dataType: 'json',
          async: false,
          data: {},
          success: function(data) {
          $.each(data.route, function(key, value) {    


       html += '<div >' + value.no + "</div>" + "</div>" 

            });

       }
```

Comment: If you're intent on using the inappropriate bootstrap for this, then just set each cell to `col-md-6`: `html += "<div class='col-md-6'>" + value.no ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `jQuery` library and a `+` when concatenating `html += '<div class="card small">' value.no + "</div>" + "</div>"` in your `jsfiddle`. You need to also add `Bootstrap` libraries.

Here is a working **[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uq5yC/134/)**

```js
var el = $('#dbg');
var row = el.find('tr');
var column = row.find('td');

var HtmlData = LoadData();
el.html(HtmlData);


function LoadData() {
  var dmJSON = "http://api.railwayapi.com/route/train/12728/apikey/3dacdecg/";
  var html = [];
  html += '<div class="row s12"/>';
  $.ajax({
    url: dmJSON,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: {},
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data.route, function(key, value) {


        html += '<div class="card small col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">' + value.no + "</div>" + "</div>"

      });

    }
  });
  return html;
}
```

```css
.card{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="dbg">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          head1
        </th>
        <th>
          head2
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
  <div>
```

Comment: @Inonut, Forget to add jquery in my fiddle. Actually, i want the result as in the picture like 1 and 2 in the first row, 3 and 4 in second and so on. Can you please help me in achieving this.

Comment: @sumanth you also need to add Bootstrap libraries and add `col-md-6` class to have two columns. I will update my answer.

Comment: still same.(these words are for sake of stackoverflow :p)

Comment: What do you mean by `these words are for sake of stackoverflow :p`? :)

Comment: it asked me to enter more than 15 characters to post a comment. By the way, in your updated answer I can still see only one column.

Comment: You can see only one column on mobile. That's how `col-md-6` works. Resize the window from jsfiddle.

Comment: @sumanth, I've also updated the answer again, added `col-sm-6` and `col-xs-6` for tablets and mobile. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Uq5yC/133/). I have fixed the code and all. Check once.

```
function LoadData()
{
 var dmJSON="http://api.railwayapi.com/route/train/12728/apikey/3dacdecg/";
 var html = '<div class="row s12"/>';
    $.ajax({
      url: dmJSON,
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      data: {},
      success: function(data) {
      $.each(data.route, function(key, value) {
         html += '<div class="card small">' + value.no + "</div>" + "</div>" 
        });
                el.html(html);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Actually i wanted the result as in the pic. can you solve it?